# How to generate android app bundle from jenkins job

Tags: android, jenkins, android-app-bundle

I have generate apk from jenkins job and publishing it to google playstore. Now i need to generate android app bundle from jenkins job. Please guide to generate aab from jenkins job. Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline#bundle_build_gradle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure your jenkins job to invoke a gradle build script.
Use the gradle task (to build the release variant)

```
./gradlew bundleRelease
```

More info in the [official doc](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline#bundle_build_gradle).

Comment: Thank you Gabriele Mariotti. I also used the execute build shell to generate .aab file by `./gradlew app:bundle`. This command generates both debug and release build also.

Comment: Hii @selvakumar can you please while using this command in the Gradle build script it generates the .aab file but while generating the artifacts at the post-build step do you specify the extension as .aab?